# know which keyword of regex was found

Tags: java, regex

If I have the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Fiat|Panda|Ford");

String searchStr =  "Fiat Panda 4747 ";
Matcher m = p1.matcher(searchStr);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Is it possible to know which of the keywords "Fiat", "Panda" or "Ford" was found?

Comment: What happened when you run that code? That should work.

Comment: Setting pattern reference `p` and using `p1` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. You had `p1`.matcher, instead you need to change it to `p`.matcher.

```
String in = "Fiat Panda 4747";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Fiat|Panda|Ford");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```